# Wordpress site for Front end, another WP for backend

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress Site with existing backend access/user logins/protected pages, etc. They want to have a new Wordpress website for the Front end, but want to retain the backend of the previous. Without modifying the existing Site, is there a way to have a WP install act as front end, while using the previous WP install for all backend? Either subdomains, HTaccess, or something else? I was considering moving first install to like agents.domain.com, and once their inside that flow it works, and have a redirect on that index.php to the domain.com for front end?

Or is there more of a boxed solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to try WordPress multisite it will help you

You need to add the following code to your wp-config.php file just before the /* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ line.

/* Multisite */

`define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );`

for more detail, you can check below link 
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Comment: How will that work with a front end WP install and backend install? Or is Multisite only helping with the subdomains?

Comment: here you can create multipale admin panels and multiple front end sites so as you whise you can use it, as power your question its impossible but if Wordpress multisite will help you

Comment: I dont know if Multisite will work. It only has 1 set of WP files for all sites. My existing site has currently it's own set, and the new front end only has another set of files.